# JQuery - preventing form from submitting not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, form-submit, preventdefault

I create a form.

How do I prevent a form from submitting using jQuery?

```
<form id="form">
  <div class="container form-group">
    <h1 class="mb-5">Get in touch!</h1>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" />
    <small class="text-muted d-block mb-3">we never share your email</small>
    <label>Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="subject" />
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea
      name="message"
      id="content"
      rows="3"
      class="form-control mb-3"
    ></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, the page refreshes again

I don't know where the problem comes from

Comment: What you've written should work.

Comment: Is the form added to the DOM dynamically? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Have you checked for any error messages on the console?

Comment: there is no error in consoleو The page is refreshed each time

Comment: Then, all else being equal, that should work. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Note that some of your labels are missing their `for` attributes and others are referencing the `name` of their target when they need to reference the `id`.

Comment: I have tested your code in my local and it works as expected, when the form is sent `preventDefault()` does its job.

Comment: So why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: Please see the answer and the working demo link added for you.